# ZF2 - issue with implementing Bootstrap Datetime picker in edit mode

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, zend-framework2

I implemented the [eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in my ZF2 application.

See here the implementation in add mode:

```
<div class="form-group <?= ($this->formElementErrors($event->get('date'))) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
<?php
 echo $this->formLabel($event->get('date')) . PHP_EOL;
 ?>
 <div class="input-group date" id='date'>
     <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </span>
     <?php
      echo $this->formText($event->get('date')) . PHP_EOL;
     ?>
 </div>
  <?php
    echo $this->formElementErrors($event->get('date')) . PHP_EOL;
  ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('#date').datetimepicker({
           format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY'
       });
    });
 </script>
```

This works fine.
In edit mode I have the same implementation, but I receive a Zend\View\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion

This is due to the fact that I pass a Date object to a Text field.
However in the eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker this needs to be an input field of type text.

Anybody suggestions on how to deal with this or maybe even a working example?

Thanks.